# Rspec don't delete 2 specific tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Rspec for testing a rails application.
I have 2 tables I imported data into (both the test and development database)

The entire application is dependent on the  tables data, meaning the entire functionality is matching, calculating and measuring data from this table and putting it into other tables.

so, when testing, there's no point in deleting these table's data but Rspec is still deleting the data from them.

my question is:
how can I force Rspec not to delete data from these tables (never, ever)?

my spec helper file

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do

end

Spork.each_run do

end


ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

Comment: What is the rspec configuration(in spec_helper) you are using? Paste it here

Comment: When is the data created? is it in seeds.rb or fixtures? If the data is created during the test run, it will be rolled back. The use_transactional_fixtures = true flag gives you this behavior. It is always good to have this option.

Comment: The data is inside the database, it is not created at any stage of the testing, I am pulling data from this table but never creating new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is
in the spec_helper.rb file I should change this

```
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

to this

```
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

In the tests where I do need the database to be cleaned, I clean it manually with delete_all or with database_cleaner (whatever convenient for you)

That solved my problem and made the database persistent through the testing.

Comment: Thanks.  Also watch out for "maintain_test_schema" in an included file - also tries to purge the DB.