# Tell Rspec - don't delete my test_db when before running tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I populate a database that I want to run rspec tests against.

Rspec seems to delete the db before it starts the tests. How can I tell Rspec not to delete this test_db?

I populate the db outside of Rails / Rspec environment. To build all the factories needed to build up the DB is just not practical for the scope of the project but I would like to test against existing DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage clean your database using [database cleaner gem](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner), and The documentation recommends the following configuration for rspec as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21323315/2791480), but you change as the following:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
end
```

But, I prefer to create your database in test environment before scenario, as example:

```
describe "specific name for this scenario" do
  before do
    @object = create(:object) # using factory girl as example
  end
end
```

so, this data'll be generate for each time you run your test-case, read more about [creating data for rspec-test](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions).

Comment: To build all the factories needed to build up the DB is just not practical for the scope of the project but I would like to test against existing DB.

Comment: I want test_db to not be deleted before or after tests. I will maintain it.

Comment: okay, you can use database cleaner to manage when to clean your data?
Doesn't work with you ?

Comment: How does database cleaner play with Rspec? When you say     DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction and     DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
does that override statements like config.use_transactional_fixtures = true in my Rspec config block?

Comment: your question is answered in this [link](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/)

Comment: Anyone have a simple answer to this question? I have an existing db, I don't want rspec to clear it before running tests. But it would be nice to have rspec reset the db after running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

I used the advice given in this question: [Rspec don't delete 2 specific tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289956/rspec-dont-delete-2-specific-tables)

In spec_helper.rb:

Commented out call to truncate_all_tables.

Then changed line:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

to

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```